# How to use Insert into

Tags: sql

I have data with field

```
TrxSeqCd     Name       Location
00001        Book       0001-A
00001        Book       0001-B
00001        Book       0001-C
```

I want duplicate the data but only location data is same, Field TrxSeqCd and Name will change with other codes and name

The data will be like this after i duplicate it

```
TrxSeqCd     Name       Location
00001        Book       0001-A
00001        Book       0001-B
00001        Book       0001-C
00002        Pen        0001-A
00002        Pen        0001-B
00002        Pen        0001-C
```

It's mean when i duplicate only location is same TrxSeqCd and Name will be change with what TrxSeqCd and Name That i want. Plz tell to me how to do it with Syntax Insert Into
Note : the Table only 1 Table Not join with other table

Answer (score 1):

You need an insert select. The query to get the additional data is

```
select '00002' as TrxSeqCd, 'Pen' as Name, Location from mytable;
```

So the insert statement becomes

```
insert into mytable (TrxSeqCd, Name, Location)
select '00002' as TrxSeqCd,  'Pen' as Name, Location from mytable;
```

or shorter

```
insert into mytable (TrxSeqCd, Name, Location)
select '00002', 'Pen', Location from mytable;
```

Comment: he wants 0002-A,B etc for 2nd  transaction

Comment: @mohan111: No. The OP says "only location is same" and the shown results match this statement.